# How to use a "private" .xcconfig in a "Shared" (git-managed) Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcconfig

Often, I'll use an existing `.xcconfig` in some submodule, to ease the integration of some git submodule (or one of my own Xcode "sub projects") within an Xcode workspace (or project).

[image: xcconfig's]

This works great, and reduces the need to make lots of local configuration changes to a project which might exist happily *on it's own*, or which I want to push contributions, upstream to (changes which are unrelated, and indeed *wholly separate* to settings introduced from the `.xcconfig`).

However, even without adding the `.xcconfig` to the project's folder... entries similar to the following..

```
+7B3453E018A38FAD00D28DF5 /* Mac-StaticLibrary.xcconfig */ = {
    isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.xcconfig; 
    name = "Mac-StaticLibrary.xcconfig"; 
    path = "/local/AtoZ.framework/AtoZAutoBox/../../xcconfigs/Mac OS X/Mac-StaticLibrary.xcconfig"; 
    sourceTree = "<absolute>"; 
};
```

and

```
+ baseConfigurationReference = 7B3453E018A38FAD00D28DF5 /* Mac-StaticLibrary.xcconfig */;
```

get added to the tracked changes inside the `$(PEOJECT_NAME).xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file, by git.

Is there ANY way to keep these modifications to the `.xcodeproj` "local"?  I hate to sully pull requests and project independence with these obviously inappropriate changes.. but would miss the convenience and functionality that this integration method offers... Any advice..